# Sessions are not being created. Error is 'Missing template sessions/create, application/create'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `create` method in my `Sessions controller`, but am still getting this error. It refers to `application/create` too, may be this is the root of my problem? I don't need a `create` method in my `application controller` too do I?

```
Template is missing

Missing template sessions/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/opt/csdashboard/app/views"
```

Here is my Session Controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    dashboard_user = DashboardUsers.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
    if dashboard_user
      session[:dashboard_user_id] = dashboard_user.id
      redirect_to index, :notice => 'Logged in'
    else
      flash.now.alert = 'Login failed'
      render new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:dashboard_user_id] = nil?
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => 'Logged out'
  end

end
```

Here are my Routes:

```
Csdashboard::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :csdashboard
  resources :dashboard_users
  resources :sessions
  get '/log_out' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => 'log_out'
  get '/log_in' => 'sessions#new', :as => 'log_in'
  post '/sign_up' => 'dashboard_users#new', :as => 'sign_up'
  post '/dashboard_users_index' => 'dashboard_users#new'
  root :to => 'dashboard_users#new'
  get 'csdashboard' => 'csdashboard#index'
  get '/img/:name.:ext', :to => redirect('/assets/%{name}.%{ext}')
  match '/404' => 'errors#not_found'
  match '/422' => 'errors#server_error'
  match '/500' => 'errors#server_error'
end
```

Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  helper_method :current_user

  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= DashboardUsers.find(session[:dashboard_user_id]) if session[:dashboard_user_id]
  end
end
```

Comment: under views there should be a `sessions` folder and inside you should have a file named `create.html.erb`

Comment: That did it, it got me past that error, thanks much! I just added a blank create.html.erb file and it seems ok. Should it be blank (no code, no html)?

Comment: funny question. if there is nothing you'd like to show there is no need to create on. Find more information about `render` on ruby-on-rails http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for `template` with name of the action. Use `render 'new'` in the action.